# Git log all, display current commit differently

Tags: git, git-log

I tend to use `git log --all --graph --oneline` a lot.

If my current state is behind the last commit, I find hardly where I am on the graph display.

Is there a way, conserving the general display (oneline, graph), to highlight the current revision in a certain way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`--pretty`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting) option of `git log` to include the [references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) (branches, tags and `HEAD`) in the list of commits:

```
git log --all --graph --pretty='%C(green)%h%Creset %C(cyan)%d%Creset %s'
```

where:

- `%C(color)` and `%Creset` change the color of the output and reset it to its default color, respectively
- `%h` expands to the abbreviated commit hash
- `%d` expands to the list of references that point to the commit
- `%s` expands to the first line of the commit message (i.e. the "*summary*")

> You can find the complete list of placeholders in the [Pretty Formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) section of the `git log` documentation.

Of course, you wouldn't want to type all this every time you want to look at history, so let's create an [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for it:

```
git config --global alias.lg \
    "log --all --graph --pretty='%C(green)%h%Creset %C(cyan)%d%Creset %s'"
```

At which point you can simply say `git lg`.

Alternatively, you can specify the default *pretty format* to use for `git log`, `git show` and `git whatchanged` in the `format.pretty` configuration setting:

```
git config --global format.pretty '%C(green)%h%Creset %C(cyan)%d%Creset %s'
```

Comment: Nice, do you think it's possible to customize the `pretty` to have a different highlight for the current commit?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Not that I know of at least. But you can always write a script that looks for a line containing `"HEAD"` using regex and apply a different color before sending it to stdout. Could then pipe the output of `git log` through that script in your alias. For example, assuming your script is called `highlight-head` you could write the alias like: `git config --global alias.lg "!git log --all --graph --pretty='<your-format-string>' | highlight-head"`